# Can someone explain the ambiguity of the vowel [ø] and null segment [∅]?

Tags: phonetics, morphology, ipa, sound-change, transcription

Typically the IPA avoids using the same glyph in different scales to represent similar ideas however it seems to me that the representation of the Close-mid Front Rounded Vowel [ø] and the null marker [∅] is needlessly ambiguous.

It's curious to me that I've never seen a linguistics text directly address this but the [IPA Unicode index](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/sites/default/files/phonsymbol.pdf) provided on the International Phonetic Associations website verifies that the vowel is represented using "ø" (U+00F8 Latin Small Letter O with Stroke) while [Wikipedia indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_(linguistics)) that the null vowel is represented by the character "∅" (U+2205 Empty Set).

The *only* differences between these two characters is scale, line weight and perhaps a slight variation in rounding.

So my question is how is this ambiguity resolved, particularly when handwriting a phonetic or morphological process?

Comment: The null marker is **not** represented by U+00D8 `Latin Capital Letter O with Stroke`, which is the letter Ø. As the Wikipedia page you link to says, it is represented by U+2205 `Empty Set`, which is the mathematical symbol ∅ that happens to look relatively close to Ø. Using Ø for the null vowel is an informal ad-hoc workaround best avoided. But since capital Ø has no IPA value, and since ø and ∅ are easily distinguishable by their quite distinct shapes, I’ve personally never found them to be ambiguous, even when Ø is used as a workaround.

Comment: in handwriting the distinction is trickier, but usually easily resolved by writing the null symbol especially large

Comment: Yeah initially when I was writing the question I misidentified the "Empty Set" character as the "Capital O with Stroke" character, then I found the wiki page. As you say, these two seem functionally interchangeably as neither is used in the IPA and both appear similar enough and in about the same scale.

Answer (score 3):

Nothingness, in phonetics, *shouldn't* be represented with Ø (Capital Letter O With Stroke), it should be represented with ∅ (Empty Set). This symbol is bigger and is shaped like a circle rather than like a letter O (which is squished horizontally in most fonts). But, some linguists made do with Ø back before ∅ had widespread font support.

Either way, though, phonologists generally don't seem to have an issue distinguishing capital from lowercase letters. Lowercase c is the IPA symbol for a voiceless palatal stop, while capital C is frequently used to mean "any consonant", and this hasn't caused too many problems.

(Though anecdotally, I did once cause a lot of frustration for myself when I used *o and *O for different reconstructed phonemes in a lecture. No issue on the slides, but trying to keep them distinct on the chalkboard was a nightmare!)

If it becomes an issue when writing about a particular language (say, one where front rounded vowels frequently get deleted), the author can choose a font that emphasizes the differences, or use a different symbol for one or the other: I've seen ö for the vowel and {} for nothingness plenty of times.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer and anecdote. Indeed the /c/ C is definitely a good example for me as I've never found this ambiguous, even in my first year in university when I was stubbornly referring to /ɯ/ as "double u" and /w/ as "small capital double u." Decoupling my own perception of letters and graphemes from my primary school days was it's own process. 

I shouldn't be peeved, but I get a little triggered when a writing system explicitly designed to relieve ambiguity instead appears to introduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction that you refer to comes from mixing two entirely different alphabets, that of formal language theory and that of the IPA. ʃ, ɛ, ɑ, ɣ which are phonetic symbols also resemble mathematical notation. The distinction between ɵ and θ is a more problematic visual distinction, since these are both IPA symbols. The symbols are similar but not identical. A rule changing /a/ to a front rounded mid vowel before [i] is informally written as "a→ø/_i" (the formal rule would involve clearly different feature expressions). A rule deleting /a/ in that context would be written as "a→Ø/_i".

The only real problem is a computer-coding problem, that in Unicode, visually-identical letters can have different codes, depending on what block they are in. Example: Greek ε and IPA ɛ. This isn't a linguistic problem, it's a computer problem.

Comment: The deletion rule may be _very_ informally written with an Ø, but in anything less informal than personal notes, it should be written as `a → ∅ /_i`.

Comment: Certainly math, logic, the IPA, a variety of alphabets—notably Greek—share the same glyphs, sometimes with related meanings, e.g. {}. I understand that in any formal contexts we shouldn't be mixing notation and keeping them in their own discrete systems, but clearly in this context ∅ is written in conjunction with the IPA to denote rules depicting a phonetic process where it disappears.

As for the actual Unicode characters I don't think personally I've had too many problems once I was able to correctly identify them.